# UITextField inside UIStackView Spacing Issue on width constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uistackview

I have a vertical `UIStackView` which has various of `UITextFields` (Now It is only 4) inside it. When I give spacing to UIStackView, I gave below error;

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286720 H:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x104d3e6f0](LTR)   (active, names: '|':Hello.OtpInputView:0x104d3c5b0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286770 UIStackView:0x104d3e6f0.right == Hello.OtpInputView:0x104d3c5b0.right   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286860 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' Hello.OtpInputView:0x104d3c5b0.width == 0   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286e50 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x104d3e6f0.leading == Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x10588d600.leading   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286ea0 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105082600]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x104d3e6f0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286f40 'UISV-fill-equally' Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105024600.width == Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x10588d600.width   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4287030 'UISV-fill-equally' Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105077a00.width == Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x10588d600.width   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c42871c0 'UISV-fill-equally' Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105082600.width == Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x10588d600.width   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286ef0 'UISV-spacing' H:[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x10588d600]-(10)-[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105024600]   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c4286fe0 'UISV-spacing' H:[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105024600]-(10)-[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105077a00]   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c42870d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105077a00]-(10)-[Hello.CustomOtpTextField:0x105082600]   (active)>"
> ```
>
> )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

How I declare StackView:

```
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.spacing = 10

//textFields is just an array of UITextFields
textFields.enumerated().forEach { (index,field) in
    field.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    field.font = Font.sourceSansRegular?.withSize(46)
    field.keyboardType = .numberPad
    field.delegate = self
    field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    field.tag = index
    field.textAlignment = .center
    field.myDelegate = self
    field.sizeToFit()
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(field)
    field.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: (CGFloat(0 / textFields.count)),constant: CGFloat(10 * (textFields.count - 1))).isActive = true
}

self.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

What I want Is that for example `UIStackView` has 110pt width and 10 space then `UITextFields` should has 20pt ((20 * 4) + (3 * 10) which is 110). Therefore, all `UITextFields` should has same width (Fill Equally)

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** I think I need to specify at least one width for one TextField so I added

```
 field.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: (CGFloat(0 / textFields.count)),constant: CGFloat(10 * (textFields.count - 1))).isActive = true
```

However this also give break error.

**EDIT2:** This stack view is in a custom UIView and I'm giving anchors inside

```
 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //Where I gave all anchors
    setupUI()
}
```

Also How I initialize this custom UIView

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(otpField)
    otpField.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 40, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 40, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 60)
}
```

What I want to achieve in a picture:

[image]

Comment: It has vertical axis. Sorry In my question, I forgot to change it.

Comment: If you mean, width anchor of UITextfield, I'm writing it after I added textfield to UIStackview.

Comment: I want it for VERTICAL and I'm doing inside custom UIView, I edited my question can you please check it?

Comment: I added how I initialize the custom UIView.

Comment: I also add a picture to be more clear.

Comment: Confusing? Your code has `stackView.axis = .horizontal`, but you're saying you want  ***"VERTICAL"***? You added an image... are the blue boxes `UITextFields`? So, do you want them laid-out as in your image? And you want to figure out how to get equal widths with 10-pt spacing?

Comment: Yes sorry I want horizontal

Comment: If you are constraining the width of your `.horizontal` stack view, and setting `.spacing = 10` and `.distribution = .fillEqually`, you shouldn't have to do anything else. (and there's no need for `field.sizeToFit()` in your loop)

Comment: I move stackview.anchor code before adding textfields and  problem solved i think.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a single constraint for height if you already set the `stackView.distribution = .fillEqually` add a constraint to any of your textFiled like this

```
let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField1, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40.0)
textField1.addConstraint = height
```

By doing this way All of your textfield will be of height 40 and the total size will depend on the number of item and spacing given for i.e. `Height = 40` , `Space = 10` Then Total height will be `(Height * Number of textfields) + (Space * (number of textfield - 1))`

> NOTE : Concept is same for vertical and horizontal stackview you need to play with height and width.

Comment: Giving specific height of 40 also breaks constraint.

Comment: this may be happening due to the relativity with other UI elements.

Comment: But my Stackview is vertical not horizontal so my problem is with width not height.

Comment: Okay so just change the height constraint to width. Can you show your ViewController